# Ember.js make model of embedded / sideloaded data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-model, serialization

To use ember validations I need to make a model of embedded data. I use Ember CLI.

The JSON looks something like this:

```
{
  "endpoint": {
    "name": "Name of form", 
    "form_settings": {
      "id": 2, 
      "setting_one": "Setting 1"
    },
    "id": 2
    }
}
```

I've made this serializer:

```
import applicationSerializer from 'closealert-ui/serializers/application';
import DS from 'ember-data';

var endpointSerializer = applicationSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
    attrs: {
        endpointFormSettings: {embedded: 'always'}
      }
});
export default endpointSerializer;
```

I've made an endpoint model:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    formName: DS.attr('string'),
    formSettings:   DS.belongsTo('endpointFormSettings'),
});
```

And I've made an enpoint-form-settings model:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    endpoint: DS.belongsTo('endpoint'),
    settingOne: DS.attr('string')
});
```

When I look in the ember inspector the endpointFormSettings model is still empty. What am I missing?

Comment: Your JSON uses `form_settings` but your model uses `formSettings`. Is that being handled in your serializer?

Comment: Hi GJK yes that's already handled in the serializer. In the console I got the error that it could not find model endpointFormsettings. Somehow it is looking for endpointFormsettings with settings in lowercase instead of capitalized. It's because of the second dash in my endpoint-form-settings.js model. Don't know why this is happening but for now it's working with endpoint-formsettings.js